# match two photos with differents settings

Tags: post-processing

I have two photos (unedited, with all the metadata added by the camera) one was taken in a studio, the other one with my cellphone. I'm wondering if it would be possible to edit the photo taken in a studio so that the colors, tone, etc... would look the same as if I had took it myself.
My goal is to see how the studio photo would look compared to the one I took with my cellphone under the same conditions.
Is it possible to do that given the photos have all the metadata the camera stored within them ?

Comment: Do you have a sample of both the studio photo and the phone image?

Comment: Also by under the same conditions does that mean you are able to use any off camera flashes? (or is lighting continuous)

Comment: Can you explain your goal more clearly? Are you trying to see how much better the studio setup is than your cell phone, or something else?

Comment: And yeah, if you can post the two specific examples, we can help you figure out how to get from one to (something like) the other.

Comment: There are videos on youtube that explain how to reverse engineer the style of a photo. (search for "photoshop reverse engineer look" or something like this) In that process the edited photo will be seen as a semi-unedited photo. So you can get rid off the color grading and global stuff like this, but not local edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do that given the photos have all the metadata the camera stored within them ?

In general, no — the metadata is just broad strokes, not a detailed forensic or scientific report.

If you are interested in really reproducing *all* characteristics of an image, you're basically down to an even-more complicated version of [this question about artificially "changing" shutter speed](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/99173/creating-a-synthetic-image-from-an-original-image-with-a-given-shutter-speed/99175#99175). (Quick version: not easily done at all!)

If you just want to replicate the colors and tones, that can generally be done, but by eye and by using tools like the image tone histogram — see [this answer about histograms](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/450/how-and-why-do-you-use-an-image-histogram/99239#99239) for some suggestion of how that works. This is because while the metadata may contain some color profile information, it doesn't include details of the *tone curves* used — or the chemical equivalent in film. (See [Is it possible to reproduce a colour tone (of any photos) perfectly (by curves)?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/53100/is-it-possible-to-reproduce-a-colour-tone-of-any-photos-perfectly-by-curves) and [How do I evaluate a camera's JPEG tone curve options when the manufacturer only provides flowery prose?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22966/how-do-i-evaluate-a-cameras-jpeg-tone-curve-options-when-the-manufacturer-only) for a bit on that.)